# File upload in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to file upload.I have tried this code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("documents")).click();     
driver.get("C:"+File.separator+"exp"+File.separator+"tt.docx");

driver.findElement(By.id("page"));
Actions ac = new Actions(driver); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("page"));                     
ac.click(element).perform();

Robot r = new Robot(); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Execution of this code the folder of file was opened but not written(file path) in text box. My input type=file is read only. Can anybody help me?

Comment: If the element is actually `<input type="file">`, you should be able to do `driver.findElement(By.id("elementId")).sendKeys("C:\\path\\to\\your\\file")`. Does that not work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,this is not working,because i think  my file input type is readonly :(,I used above mentioned code but somewhere it is stucking

Comment: What do you mean "read only"? The `sendKeys` method should properly handle the file selection dialog, even if the `<input>` element is rendered as read-only. Can you provide a sample demonstrating the failure? I'm quite sure `sendKeys` works for file uploads; I use it routinely without incident.

Comment: Are you using Robot framework with Selenium WebDriver?